# Gradle - change main distribution - get rid of bin and lib folders

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Gradle build with application plugin applied. Application plugin also applies distribution plugin and creates default `main` distribution, which will place startup scripts in `bin` folder, and dependencies in `lib`.

Now I want to completely remove that default behavior and have my own distribution but with the same name `main`. To be more precise I don't want `bin` and `lib` folders and want my custom content.

I know I can easily define a new distribution like

```
distributions {
    my {
        // my configuration here
    }
}
```

so I can produce desired distribution via `myDistZip` for example.

But I want to change exactly `main` distribution so I will be able to produce archive via simple `distZip` (or `distTar`).

I tried to remove main distribution (via `distributions.remove(distributions.main)`) and create new one

```
distributions {
    main {
        // my configuration here
    }
}
```

but that fails with

```
Cannot add task ':distZip' as a task with that name already exists.
```

I guess this is simply because Gradle creates `distZip` tasks for every new distribution, so it was trying to do that for new `main` as well, however `distZip` task was already created during plugin application.

So is there any way to change `main` distribution to get rid of `bin` and `lib` folders?

Gradle: 3.5

Answer (score 1):

> But I want to change exactly main distribution so I will be able to produce archive via simple distZip (or distTar).

It seems like you don't have to change `main` distribution - the documentation for `distribution` plugin (added automatically by `application` plugin) notes that for each distribution, so you can use `gradle myDistZip`.

However it seems that you should be able to configure existing `main` distribution as well:

```
distributions {
  main {
    contents {
      // configure
    }
  }
}
```

While you can't reset existing values it seems, maybe you could use exclusions to not copy specific folders (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html)